# Migrate database from one server to another without downtime

Tags: mysql, migration

I want to migrate a MySQL database to another MySQL database (different server and only terminal access). I believe I can do a dump on it, but then I won't have the latest data. How do I make sure that I have the latest data if I am not allowed to have downtime? Is it possible?

Please excuse my ignorance if any (newbie in dba). I have read all the suggestions and duplicate questions before creating this new one. But none of them seems to be the one I am looking for.

Comment: If you have not _already_ set up replication or LVM, you will incur downtime.

Answer (score -1):

In general I don't think it's possible to move a database without any downtime with MySQL standard tools.

However you can try to use mysqldump and mysqlbinlog to minimize "data loss": see section "Example: mysqldump + mysqlbinlog for Backup and Restore" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog-backup.html

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to setup master-master replication (tons of docs available)

Initial replica setup can be made by `mysqldump` with `--master-data` option. I hope you have used InnoDB engine for all the tables so dump will use a consistent snapshot with no locking.

Then you'll get the pair of syncronized servers that propagates writes to each other.

If you have used `MariaDB` fork instead of `MySQL` then you have also an option to use `Galera cluster` functionality that acts exactly like M-M replication but has a lot of advantages including self-initialization of the new-added nodes.